# Excel VBA Macro -- Custom margins are not saving

Tags: vba, excel

In my script, I am setting customer margins.  They look good in the code, however when I run the script on a new sheet, it retains the standard 1" margins.

Any suggestions as to how I can get them to stick?

```
Sub Target_Format()
'
' Target_Format Macro
'
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=66
    Rows("85:112").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-42
    Rows("43:70").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-72
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("15:15").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Rows("28:28").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Rows("41:41").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-30
    Rows("14:14").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A14").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Rows("28:28").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Rows("42:42").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("I39").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
    Range("A42:H42").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    Range("A42:H42,A28:H28").Select
    Range("A28").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-15
    Range("A42:H42,A28:H28,A14:H14").Select
    Range("A14").Activate
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("I22").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
    Rows("15:28").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("I20").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-24
    Columns("I:O").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Rows("2:7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("A2:H2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Actual"
    Range("B4:H7").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
    Rows("5:5").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("I10").Select
    Rows("5:5").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("7:7").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("9:9").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "WTD"
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "WTD"
    Range("A9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "WTD"
    Rows("11:11").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A11:H11").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("A11").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "WTD"
    Range("A5:H5,A7:H7,A9:H9,A11:H11").Select
    Range("A11").Activate
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("J9").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-12
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.15)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.15)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = 600
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With

    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("A2:H2").Select
    Selection.UnMerge
    Range("B2:H2").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = -16777216
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "/"
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "/"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "/"
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "/"
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "/"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "/"
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "/"
    Range("B2:H2").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("A1:H1").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range("A2").Activate
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("C:I").Select
    Range("C2").Activate
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 7.57
    Range("A1").Select

    'Macro 5
    Columns("B:H").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Week #"
    Range("J1").Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone

    'Macro 7
    Columns("J:J").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 1.43
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are disabling `PrintCommunication` just before setting your margins:

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False ' <-- disables print communication
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
```

but you never enable it again with an `Application.PrintCommunication = True`, so the changes are never committed.

Refer to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835544.aspx) for more information.

---

P.S. I would strongly recommend that you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/6535336) to find ways of avoiding `Select` and `Selection`.